# What the selector means?

Tags: jquery

Can you explain what the following selector mean?

**$("input:checkbox.compbox")**

Thank you.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's looking for elements like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="compbox" />
```

It's looking for three things:

- An input element type, `<input />`
- Specifically, a `type="checkbox"` input
- An element with a class of `compbox`

Since the selector has no spaces, it's look for individual elements that meets **all three** criteria, not children/descendants or anything like that.  For additional info, [you can find a full list of selectors here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), [a great getting started guide here](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:Getting_Started_with_jQuery#Find_me:_Using_selectors_and_events) and [a video tutorial on selectors here](http://brightcove.vo.llnwd.net/pd11/media/87100853001/87100853001_88537065001_TVM-J002-jQuery-Selectors.mp4).